# java inheritance and late binding

Tags: java, inheritance, late-binding

I understand how the following code works, based on polymorphism and dynamic binding.  Java is somehow able to figure out at runtime that because vh is a MotorBike, we should call MotorBike's move() method.

```
class Vehicle{
    public void move(){
        System.out.println(“Vehicles can move!!”);
    }
}

class MotorBike extends Vehicle{
    public void move(){
        System.out.println(“MotorBike can move and accelerate too!!”);
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vehicle vh=new MotorBike();
        vh.move();    // prints MotorBike can move and accelerate too!!
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why the following code breaks.  the only change I've made is to delete the move() method from the Vehicle class.  Now I get a compile error that says "cannot find symbol - method move()".  Why is this so?  Why does the previous example work and this code doesn't?

```
class Vehicle{
}

class MotorBike extends Vehicle{
    public void move(){
        System.out.println(“MotorBike can move and accelerate too!!”);
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vehicle vh=new MotorBike();
        vh.move();    // compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you have told the compiler that the `vh` reference points to a `Vehicle`, and all `Vecicle`s don't have a `move()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Java has two closely-related concepts that are both relevant here:

- Every expression has a *type*, which is determined at compile-time. The variable `vh` has type `Vehicle`, so the expression `vh` (consisting of just that variable) has type `Vehicle`.

  - The expression `new MotorBike()`, by the way, has type `MotorBike`, but since that's a subtype of `Vehicle`, the compiler can convert from the former to the latter.
- Every object has a *runtime-type* — the class that it's an instance of — which is determined at runtime. `new MotorBike()` creates an object with runtime-type `MotorBike`.

When you write `vh.move()`, if the `Vehicle` class doesn't have a method called `move`, then the compiler has no idea what you're talking about.

If `Vehicle` *does* have a method called `move`, then the compiler can compile it just fine, and leaves it to the runtime to examine the actual runtime-type of the corresponding instance and dispatch to the right method. (Or to raise a `NullPointerException` if there *is* no corresponding instance, and therefore no relevant runtime-type.)

There are some languages, generally called "dynamically typed" (or "untyped" or "dynamic"), that don't have this concept of *type*, and only the concept of *runtime-type*. Such languages include Perl, Python, JavaScript, and many others. In such languages, the analogue of `vh.move()` would be accepted just fine in all cases, and the runtime would verify that the method exists before calling it. But Java programmers prefer a somewhat smarter compiler, that helps us detect more bugs at compile-type.